# Suggestion needed for NON JavaScript version of an input autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, compatibility

I'm building an App that is heavy on jQuery. Most of it I can handle without the use of JS and still have a functioning site, however there is one bit that is eluding me. (note, I'm using ASP.NET MVC but that shouldn't matter in this instance)

I have an input field that is making great use of jQuery-UI AutoComplete.  The behavior is very simple. The user is asked to input their City, but is given an  AutoComplete list of valid cities.  If the city is invalid, the server side validation fires and tells them to try again.

If they do select a valid city, the jQuery method updates a hidden field that contains the CityID of the selected city.  This is working phenomenally well, and I really like the performance.

Here's where the problem enters.  If JS is not available in the browser, the ID field is not updated, and hence the DB is not updated.  I am not using the AutoComplete input on the server side at all, just the ID field.  What would be a good solution to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason sje397's answer doesn't work for you (it's an elegant solution, unless the city auto-select is based on some other field on-screen, such as a zip code or state), simply POST both fields.  When evaluating the POSTed data, if the CITY text box has data, and the hidden field does not, then evaluate the entered city using the same validation method used by the jquery callback.  If the hidden field has data, you assume that javascript is enabled and use your current logic.

Comment: Hmm, I like both options.  I'm gonna have to ponder this a little more.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. I think I'll use your scenario.  It makes much more sense to me over a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 3):

Default to a select element containing the cities as options and id's as values, and change it to the autocomplete field with the script on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

1 - Serve HTML initially that shows the "hidden" input, and doesn't include the "autocomplete" one. When JS loads, have a function edit the DOM to your current situation.

2 - Have the form default to send the "autocomplete" data to the server. Use javascript to edit the "send" function to have it switch to the "hidden" input.

Answer (score 0):

Get the page to by default to send the input of the user over the intertubes to your server, if javascript is enabled, change it so it only sends the ID over instead (using javascript obviously).